# CarrierWave doesn't work in very very simple step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I just want to add an image in my 'Item'model.
So I used carrierwave and it is not my first using of carrierwave.
But, It doesn't working.

```
storage :file
 def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end
 def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end
end
```

It is image_uploader.rb
and I add next 2 sentences in my item.rb

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
mount_uploader :image_url, ImageUploader
```

and I also permit image_url as parameter in items_controller.

There is similar project that I made last week, so I tried copy and paste of their code, but It's not working too.
I use devise and scaffold. Are there any conflicts of them?

Comment: What is not working? What does the log say?

Comment: There is no error but the image isn't saved. And the image_url column is empty after saving.

Comment: Is the item valid?

Comment: what does valid mean? Other parameters are saved properly.

Comment: Use `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader` instead of `mount_uploader :image_url, ImageUploader`